# How to launch MonoDevelop in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, mono, ide

After following those instructions:

[How to install mono on ubuntu 64-bit v14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497358/how-to-install-mono-on-ubuntu-64-bit-v14-04)

Then, how to launch MonoDevelop in Ubuntu?

Comment: I have suggested revision to your question; at first I thought you meant "MonoDevelop" (the IDE). But on second thought, did you mean `mono-devel` package? These are two different things.